# For what values $q,r$ does the improper integral $\int_0^1 x^q (1-x^2)^r dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

**Question:**

> For what values $q,r$ does the improper integral $\int_0^1 x^q (1-x^2)^r dx$ converge?

I had some ideas from a previous thread but now I have a different attempt that I would like to get comments on from the community. How does the following stand to show that we demand $p,q >-1$?

**Attempt:**

First, we notice that the function can only go to infinity as it approaches the endpoints. As $x \to 1$, we have
$$ x^q (1-x^2)^r = 1^q(1-x)^r(1+1)^r \approx (1-x)^r.$$
And as $x \to 0$, we have
$$ x^q (1-x^2)^r = x^q(1-0)^r(1+0)^r \approx x^q.$$
These lead to the familiar integrand forms
$$ \int_a^b \frac{1}{x^p} dx$$
and
$$ \int_a^b \frac{1}{(b-x)^{-p}} dx $$
which both converge for $p > -1$.
Hence, we conclude that the integral converges for $r,q > -1$.

Comment: Substitute $u=x^2$ and compare to the beta function.

Comment: It is entirely unclear how you get the equality at the end. That formula can't be true, because it gives $0$ for $r,q>0$, which is false, and nothing in your argument assumes $r,q<0$...

Comment: I see I have some work to do. Is the general direction of my approach correct? As in, I tried to identify that the integral can only go to infinity near the endpoints, so we should find the appropriate values of $r,q$ there. How can I approach the problem in this way?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. I made an edit to my approach. Does this make sense?